# Is there any way to change color of a span text per given duration?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a span tag where I display some text dynamically over some duration, essentially I am reading webvtt file and showing the text on span based on duration.

The thing is that I want to change the color of the text during the given duration,

I have tried doing this via css using data-text with transtions and passing the duration dynamically like below:

**html tag:**

```
<span :data-text="lyric1" class="word" 
:style="'animation-duration:'+duration+'s'">{{ lyric }}
</span>
```

**js function:**

```
showSubtitles(){
    for(let i = 0; i < this.subtitles.length; i++){
        if(this.songStart * 1000 >= this.subtitles[i].start
            && this.songStart * 1000 <= this.subtitles[i].end
        ){
            this.duration =(this.subtitles[i].end - this.subtitles[i].start) / 1000;
            this.lyric = this.lyric1 =  this.subtitles[i].part;
        }
    }
   this.lyricTimer =  setTimeout(function(){this.showSubtitles()}.bind(this), 500);
}
```

**css:**

```
.word::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10;
  color: #FFC61E;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0%;
  animation: run-text 10s infinite linear;
  animation-duration:inherit;
}

@keyframes run-text {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}
```

So I am giving the right duration for that time, but the transitions are just messing up like not finishing in that duration overlapping with one another or not working as expected at all.

I am suspecting that this has to do with css not being able to keep up with such dynamic changes? I would appreciate any idea on how I would go about this issue native js or vue framework?

Comment: Did you try doing this without passing in duration dynamically, to isolate the issue?

Comment: Why are you setting the animation-duration property twice (10s and inherit)? Do you need CSS transitions or animations? If you want to change the color of the text, why are you animating the width property?

Comment: @AntonijaŠimić thats left from the try/fail attempts however I am seting it to `inherit` as I am passing it dynamically. I want to change color of the text like a karaoke thing.

Comment: @montrealist yes I have tried that and it works nicely just as I want like a karaoke text changing color over the initial duration, the issue appears when I try to make duration dynamic.

Comment: do you really need to do this "recursive"? I mean, the function call itself constantly... If you already know the duration, why don't you set the "setTimeout" in the beginning?

Comment: @AriWaisberg yeah the thing is that I am picking the duration from the file it self, and it changes dynamically all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the WebVTT file, you can easily style the subtitle cue's (texts) right from the WebVTT file as explained in the link below:

[Style WebVTT file within itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API#Within_the_WebVTT_file_itself)

Comment: Yeah I do have access to 25 different webvtt files with roughly 200kb of data each... not to sure if it would be a solid approach, I am trying to code the solution instead of designing it.

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to come up with a script that will generate the WebVTT files with styles inside them than do things on the fly. Can always assess the time investment for each approach and decide.